# JQuery slim scroll doesn't scroll to the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slimscroll

I have a dashboard with a left-side bar. The bar has a lot of elements in it (including inner lists, etc). Obviously, it didn't fit in such a small area. The solution was to use a slim scroll by JQuery. The problem I have encountered, though, is unavailability to scroll to the very last element inside the bar.

The bar looks like this (without scrolling)

[image]

Now take a look at how it looks when inner elements are open:
[image]

See? The very last element cannot be seen properly (although it is clickable). Unfortunately, the only way to "fix" it is perphaps use some parameters, while initializing this stuff. Now it looks like this:

```
$('.elemToAddScrolling').slimScroll({
            height: '100%',
            wheelStep: 5,
        });
```

Basically I see that the library generates div elements - one of them is `slimScrollBar` - exactly what I look for. I see that it has `top` property, and whenever I scroll it alters. The maximum value, though, is `107px` (when we reach "the end"). I use the latest version of this plugin - 1.3.8 Is there a way to customize it really?

Comment: Issue reproduced [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qyXmaz). Do you have this `.elemToAddScrolling` inside a `100vh` container, by any chance? The height error, in the codepen comes from the padding of the body. If you apply the CSS reset in the settings, the issue is gone.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but my container has 2 styles
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;

Comment: Nothing on the body that could offset ? That was a guess, anyway. And if you try `100vh` in the slimScroll setting? Maybe...

Comment: I'm sure that is about padding somewhere... I can't believe the plugin has such a dumb issue.

Comment: Well, it seems, that you are right. Outer wrapper has `padding-top:44px` But I cannot get rid of it, because otherwise the entire page, including content, left-side bar and top bar goes up.

Comment: Ha-ha!.ok... But you can apply a `margin-top:-44px` to the inner container. ;)

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved :)
Write you answer, so I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was reproduced [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qyXmaz).

So it was clear that it was a padding issue from a parent element. Now which one? In the codepen, it was the body... In J. Doe's project, it was on an outer wrapper were he found a 44px padding.

The issue was fixed by applying a `margin-top:-44px` to the inner container... To move the whole thing up.

But, another way could have been to apply `height: calc(100% - 44px)` in the slimScroll settings! It can take it, as you can see it [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qyXmaz).